# How to concatenate numpy.ndarray and scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix with same number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, one-hot-encoding

I loaded two parts of a dataset: continuous and categorical variables. These variables were encoded using MinMax scaler and OneHot encoder, correspondingly.

```
continuous_features = ["Col1", "Col2"]
categorical_features = ["Col3", "Col4"]

min_max_enc = joblib.load('minmaxscaler.pkl')
one_hot_enc = joblib.load('onehotencoder.pkl')

df_minmaxEncoded = min_max_enc.transform(df[continuous_features])
df_onehotEncoded = one_hot_enc.transform(df[categorical_features])
```

Then I need to concatenate these datasets:

```
dataset = pd.concat([df_minmaxEncoded,df_onehotEncoded], axis=1)
```

They have the same number of rows. But the problem is that `df_minmaxEncoded` in Numpy array (`numpy.ndarray`), and `df_onehotEncoded` is `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`.

How can I convert both of them to Pandas DataFrame and concatenate?

Comment: `pd.concat([df_minmaxEncoded,df_onehotEncoded.todense()], axis=1)` ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid`

Comment: It appears you have to convert both to dataframe

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df_minmaxEncoded), pd.DataFrame(df_onehotEncoded.todense())], axis=1)`

Comment: @DaniMesejo its works thanks